# Joda DateTimeFormatter changing date while parsing

Tags: java, jdbc, jodatime, datetime-format

I have a problem while using Joda DateTimeFormatter.
Please help me out !!

This is how my Formatter looks like-

**final static DateTimeFormatter inJodaFmter
            = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");**

I am making a JDBC call and getting date as a String.

**resultSet.getString(10) is returning "2013-12-06 00:00:00"**

However, while formatting it with Joda DateTimeFormatter it is changing as below.

inJodaFmter.parseLocalDateTime(resultSet.getString(10)) = (org.joda.time.LocalDateTime) **2013-01-06T00:00:00.000**

which is wrong. 
Please suggest.

Comment: What is YYYY? What is DD? Why do you think so?

Comment: [link] http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle(java.lang.String) my bad..should have gone through it before posting. :)

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use smart objects, not dumb strings.

```
java.time.LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class )
```

## java.time

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange java.time objects with your database via `getObject` & `setObject` methods. Use objects rather than mere strings to communicate with a database.

### No zone

If drawing data from a column defined in a type similar to the standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `LocalDateTime` class.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

### UTC

If drawing data from a column defined in a type similar to the standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `Instant` class or `ZonedDateTime` class.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved using pattern
**DateTimeFormat.forPattern("Y-M-d H:m:s")**

Source - 
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try like this;

```
public class Test {
    static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTime = "2013-12-06 00:00:00";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
        DateTime jodatime = formatter.parseDateTime(dateTime);
        System.out.println(jodatime);

    }
}
```